# Turn JS array into individual objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im pretty new to JS and havent been able to find an answer searching so I'm hoping someone could help me out.

I have a csv that I parsed into an array of arrays.
It looks something like this

```
["Teacher 1", "Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 4", "Student 5"]
["Teacher 2", "Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 4", "Student 5"]
```

and so on..

I would like to break it down into objects and arrays such as this

```
Var Teacher1 = new Teacher("Teacher1");
Teacher1.students = [Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4, Student5];
```

If someone could lead me in the right direction, I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: why not just an object with an array of teacher : [array of students] key pairings?

Comment: show us the code where you get the csv into an array of arrays, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should prefer to use object and array literals instead of 'new' syntax.  for example where row is you original array:

```
// map takes an array and returns and modifies each object, passed
// as the parameter d
rows.map(function(d){
    return {
        teacher: d[0],
        students: d.slice(1)
    };

});
```

That should return a list of objects of the form

```
[
  {teacher: 'Teacher 1', students: ['Student 1', 'Student 2',...']},
]
```

More info about [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

And here an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/s1nrxwdq/).

---

Edit:
In your example that you give, you are using constructor functions to create objects with 'new' syntax.  you could create a constructor function like so

```
function Teacher(name){
  this.name = name;
}
```

so that when you call

```
var teacher = new Teacher('teacher 1')
```

you create a teacher object with a name property.  Since this is just an object, you can add whatever properties you want to it, like .students.

However, you can also get the same results by just declaring an object literal, that is

```
var teacher = {};  //an empty object
```

and then assigning properties to it

```
teacher.name = 'teacher 1';
teacher.students = ['student 1', ...]
```

or you could even just do it in one step

```
var teacher = {
  name: 'teacher 1',
  students: ['student 1',' student 2',...']
};
```

finally you can create a function that takes an array and returns this teacher object,

```
function example(item) {
  // where item is an array
  return {
     name: item[0],
     students: item.slice(1)  // takes all the array elements after 0
  };
}
```

then map that function to each element in your array using .map, and you will get an array of teacher objects

If you want to use a constructor function instead, you can use

```
function Teacher(name, students) {
  this.name = name;
  this.students = students;
}
```

and then in place of the existing function inside of map, use

```
rows.map(function(d){
  return new Teacher(d[0], d.slice(1));
});
```

However the result will be the same as the object literal notation

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So in my problem there are 24 teacher -> student combos.
Is there a way to loop through the array to create something like the first part of your answer {teacher: 'Teacher 1', students: ['Student 1', 'Student 2',...']}.. for each teacher?

Comment: is it in an array of arrays like above?  try plugging in the above function for rows

here is a codepen, run it in a js console - http://codepen.io/pen/?editors=011

Comment: @user5424235 if you know that the teacher is always going to be the first object in each array you can just repeat the process for each array in a simple loop (a loop which will run for the number of array you have)

Answer (score 0):

Without changing too much about how you already have this set up:

```
var myProcessedCSV = [
    ["Teacher 1", "Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 4", "Student 5"]
    ["Teacher 2", "Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 4", "Student 5"]
]

// start the processing
myProcessedCSV.forEach(processCSVRow);

// this function takes a single row and instantiates a Teacher object
// with it
function processCSVRow(row){
     // this extracts the teacher's name (the first data in the row)
     var teacherName = row.shift();
     var teacher = new Teacher(teacherName);
     // all the remaining data points in the row are students, so we 
     // can simply use 'row' here
     teacher.students = row;
}
```

If you need an array of the Teacher instances for later use, use "map" instead of "forEach" and return the teacher variable at the end of the "processCSVRow" function to end up with an array of instances of Teacher

Some of the other suggestions voiced here are good to consider.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this answer! it actually does exactly what I needed, but I molded the answer above to my needs before I saw it.